# How can my Chart.js custom interaction mode use 'nearest' functionality?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart that implements a custom interaction mode called myCustomMode in the options:

```
interaction: {
 intersect: false,
  mode: 'myCustomMode',
  axis : 'x'
},
```

However, now the events only get called when the user is exactly on the x-axis vs when they are 'near'. If I change the mode to the nearest I see the desired behavior but then can't implement my customizations (updated annotations). Is there any way to have a custom mode AND have the nearest mode by somehow extending Chart.js's current function somehow?

Here is my custom mode function:

```
Interaction.modes.myCustomMode = function(chart, e, options, useFinalPosition) {
  const position = getRelativePosition(e, chart);
  console.log("X:"+position.x);
  
  const items = [];
  Interaction.evaluateInteractionItems(chart, 'x', position, (element, datasetIndex, index) => {
    
    if (element.inXRange(position.x, useFinalPosition) && index_tracker!=index) {
        
        index_tracker=index;
        /*const activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(ev,, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
        const firstPoint = activePoints[0];
        const datasetIndex = firstPoint.datasetIndex;
        index = firstPoint.index;*/
        
        items.push({element, datasetIndex, index});
        const xLabel = chart.data.labels[index];
        const yValue1 = chart.data.datasets[0].data[index];
        const yValue2 = chart.data.datasets[1].data[index];
        chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].xMin = index-0.5;
        chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].xMax = index+0.5;
        chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations[1].label.content = [xLabel+' : Stay home','USD '+yValue1.toLocaleString()];
        chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations[2].label.content = [xLabel+' : Go study','USD '+yValue2.toLocaleString()];
        /* This code ensures the point hover only changes with the annotation code, but they we lose the 
        really cool 'nearest' mode of interaction which I cant replicate in this function. We can either:
        -- leave as and get cool interaction but values only update when exactly on new X point OR
        -- uncomment code below to only update point hover when exactly on X point (uncool and get 2 points instead of 1 sometimes) OR
        -- uncomment code below and move mode:"myCustomMode" from ToolTip to Interaction in options to have most uncool verison
        -- Finally (preferred) we could try to implement 'nearest' functionality here by somehow extending their mode but can't figure this out?
        
        //Change hover points - sure a better way to do this
        chart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        chart.data.datasets[0].pointBorderWidth = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        chart.data.datasets[0]['pointRadius'][index] = 6;
        chart.data.datasets[0]['pointBorderWidth'][index] = 5;
        
        chart.data.datasets[1].pointRadius = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        chart.data.datasets[1].pointBorderWidth = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        chart.data.datasets[1]['pointRadius'][index] = 6;
        chart.data.datasets[1]['pointBorderWidth'][index] = 5;
        */
        chart.update();    
    }
  });
  return items;
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can invoke the nearest interaction mode from you code and then use the result for your customization. Chart.Interaction.nearest(....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand weel the use case but I think it could be something like that:

```
Interaction.modes.myCustomMode = function(chart, e, options, useFinalPosition) {
  const nearestItems = Interaction.modes.nearest(chart, e, {axis: 'x', intersect: false}, useFinalPosition);
  
  const items = [];
  for (const element of nearestItems) {
      const index = element.index;
    if (index_tracker != index) {
        index_tracker = index;
        items.push(element);
        const xLabel = chart.data.labels[index];
        const yValue1 = chart.data.datasets[0].data[index];
        const yValue2 = chart.data.datasets[1].data[index];
        chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.box.xMin = index - 0.5;
        chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.box.xMax = index + 0.5;
        chart.update();    
    }
  };
  return items;
};
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/yLRBQwK

EDIT: add info

The official documentation about the custom interaction is here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#custom-interaction-modes

But I think you have already had a look on that, seeing your code.
Unfortunately the doc doesn't explain well that the "default" modes are stored in the map where you are adding new one. Maybe an improvement could be done.
Anyway there is a discussion in GH where a similar topic is touched: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/discussions/11148
If I may, also how you are managing the annotations options could be improved going to scriptable options. If you can share the whole chart options, I could suggest some updates to you.

Comment: Many thanks, bugged me for days. Would you mind sharing a link to the docs for this as searched high and wide?

Comment: I will edit the answer adding some info.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much, really appreciate the support.